# Ideas of how to find the distribution of Gamma(N,$\lambda$), with N~Geom($\alpha$)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this, could I use the definition of the MGF or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if  $X\sim \text{Gamma}(N,\lambda)$ then
$$
X\stackrel{d}{=}X_1+\dotsb+X_N
$$
where $X_i\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ are i.i.d exponential random variables with rate parameter equal to $\lambda$. It follows by the law of total expectation that 
$$
M_{X}(t)=Ee^{tX}=g_{N}(M_{X_1}(t))
$$
where $g_N$ is the probability generating function of $N$ and $M_{X_1}$ is the moment generating function of $X_1$.

You can do something similar using characteristic functions and then invert using the inversion formula.